# Need help to display list if cases based on contact name present on current case on record page

Tags: visualforce, case

Need help to create vf page where i want to display list of cases on case record page, created by same contact of current case. Also it will based on 2 custom fields values(i.e. product & Component). Based on these 3 fields i want make vf page and display it under case record page.

i have created vf page and controller but not sure how to proceed with criteria.

vf page:

```
<apex:page standardController="Case" recordSetVar="c" extensions="caselistcontroller">
<apex:pageBlock >
    <apex:pageBlockTable value="{!c}" var="cs">
        <apex:column value="{!cs.CaseNumber}"/>
        <apex:column value="{!cs.Products__c}"/>
       <apex:column value="{!cs.ContactId}"/>
    </apex:pageBlockTable>
</apex:pageBlock>
```

Controller:

for controller till the point to fetch contact id from case i have written logic.

```
public class caselistcontroller 
    {
    public Contact con{get;set;}
    public Case caseObject{get;set;}

      public caselistcontroller(ApexPages.StandardsetController controller)
        {
            con = new Contact();
            caseObject = new case();
            caseObject = (Case)controller.getRecord();
            //Get the Currently logged in community user contact id
            String cntId = [SELECT Id, ContactId, Name FROM User WHERE Id =: UserInfo.getUserId()].ContactId;
            caseObject.ContactId = cntId;
        }

    }
```

Can any one guide me in right direction. That would be helpful.

Case record page where contact and product is blank.
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Below controller should help you

```
public class caselistcontroller { 
    public Case caseObject{get;set;}
    public List<Case> casesWithSameContacts {get;set;}
    public Case tCase {get;set;}
    public caselistcontroller(ApexPages.StandardController controller) { 
        caseObject = (Case)controller.getRecord(); 
        tCase = [Select Id, ContactId from Case where ID=: caseObject.Id];
        casesWithSameContacts = new List<Case>();
        casesWithSameContacts = [select id, CaseNumber,Products__c,ContactId from Case where ContactId =: tCase.ContactId and Id !=:caseObject.Id];
    }
}
```

And your visualforce page should be

```
<apex:page standardController="Case" extensions="caselistcontroller">
    <apex:form>
        <apex:pageBlock >
            <apex:pageBlockTable value="{!casesWithSameContacts}" var="cs">
                <apex:column value="{!cs.CaseNumber}"/>
                <apex:column value="{!cs.Products__c}"/>
               <apex:column value="{!cs.ContactId}"/>
            </apex:pageBlockTable>
        </apex:pageBlock>
    </apex:form>
</apex:page>
```

Only change I had done is to query on other cases which had the same contact Id as the current case. And removed recordSetVar from visualforce page.

Comment: I have tried the above code, it is giving me error as "Unexpected token 'caseObject.Id'."

Comment: Forgot to add colon ":" in SOQL query. Updated the answer

Comment: Hi Vijay, i can see case list on record page but this list is having contact name and product as blank. i want to display list of cases whose contact id is same as current case record page. i have added snap into question for your reference.

Comment: If that is what your requirement is, then I updated the answer, this updated answer should work for you.

Comment: i have tried the same thing but it didn't work. i have checked in debug logs it is not picking up current case's id. could you please help me with that

Comment: That was because you are not getting the record from standard controller which would not fetch ContactId. I updated the answer again, please check if this works !!

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/89545/discussion-between-snehal-gaware-and-vijay-ganji).

Comment: it is now showing error as "List has no rows for assignment to SObject"
i have created that vf page and add it into the case record page. Is there any way where i can fetch the id that case record?